# How to fix 'error : unknown option --projectRoot' in react native

Tags: react-native

"While running 'react-native run-android' command metro server gives this error."

Here is the error Image: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NRoc.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading from react native 0.60.0 to 0.59.9 worked for me

in package.json:

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.9"
```